# Get all products in the catalog from my Module controller in 2.1.5

Tags: product, magento-2.1, module, catalog, model

I'm in a controller's action in a module I just created. How can I get an array with all the products I got in my catalog?

I did this, but it's not returning the items in the catalog

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->getCollection();
```

Plus, where can I find this kind of information? I'm starting on Magento these last days and everything is just too dificult to learn and find

For example, where is the documentation for 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product' ? And for Object Manager?

I'm in Magento 2.1.5

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use constructor to get the model instead using object manager, so in your construct, you can try this:

```
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    ) {
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    }
```

In the function:

```
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
```